# Fortran Subroutine that changes byte order

Tags: fortran

I have coded a routine in Fortran to perform reverse byte order. This will be equivalent to `src="1234"; dst="4321"`. I want to change the routine to to arbitrary ordering specified using the variables `src` and `dst` to set the ordering positions.

Here is the code for reverse byte ordering.

```
Subroutine byteorder (src, dst, x, y)

Real, Intent (out) :: y
Character (Len=*), Intent (in) :: src, dst 
Real, Intent (in)  :: x

Integer :: i, j

i = Transfer (x, 0)
Call Mvbits (i, 24, 8, j,  0 )
Call Mvbits (i, 16, 8, j,  8 )
Call Mvbits (i,  8, 8, j, 16 )
Call Mvbits (i,  0, 8, j, 24 )
y = Transfer (j, 0.0)

End Subroutine byteorder
```

Comment: What is your question? What exactly should dst and src mean?

Comment: The above is equivalent to `src="1234"; dst="4321"`. I want to make it work on the ordering I supply. For example `src="1234"; dst="2143"`. The important is the destination variable `dst`. The 32 bit real number has 4 bytes. `dst` illustrates where each byte goes with respect to the input.

Comment: Do you need it to be fast?

Comment: I suppose it is called a permutation, yes.

Comment: It would help if it was fast but not necessary. What would be the options?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could wrap something like this

```
  CHARACTER(len=4) :: src, dst
  CHARACTER(len=1), DIMENSION(4) :: src_arr, dst_arr
  INTEGER, DIMENSION(4) :: permutation

  permutation = [2,4,3,1]

  src_arr = TRANSFER(src,src_arr)
  dst_arr = src_arr(permutation)
  dst = TRANSFER(dst_arr,dst)
```

into a subroutine.

Fast enough ?  You decide.

EDIT: My use of character variables for `src` and `dst` seems to have caused some confusion.  The approach works just as well if `src` and `dst` are reals, or integers, something like:

```
  REAL :: src, dst
```

Just take care to ensure that the character arrays have the same number of 1-byte elements as there are bytes in `src` and `dst`. I've used characters for the intermediate representation since these map 1:1 with bytes (on almost all computers you are likely to encounter) and I've transferred a 4-byte scalar to a 4 element array of 1-byte scalars to make it easy to permute using Fortran's inbuilt indexing capabilities.  It's also easier to see what is going on if `src` and `dat` are character variables, otherwise `src_arr` and `dst_arr` are often meaningless jumbles of non-existent characters when written out.

Comment: No need to call `mvbits` then.

Comment: Yeas, I also thought about a vector subscript when writing my comment, +1

Comment: I am confused, why are things done with `Character` rather than real types?

Comment: You're confused ?!   Your variables `src` and `dst` are character variables.  But if you want to permute the bytes in a real, `transfer` it to a `character, dimension(4)` array and carry  on.

Comment: I thought I was required to transfer to an integer.

Comment: No. `src` and `dst` represent the byte order I want. The two can be scrapped and I can just pass the variable `permutation`. `x` is the real input, `y` is the real output with bytes reordered.

Comment: @Zeus Your original naming is pretty confusing. Just use `x` and `y` instead and derive the array `permutation` from your `src` and `dst` yourself. Character, or real, it does not matter.

Comment: Why calling `mvbits` not needed anymore? Apologies for not thinking it through well enough concerning variable names.

Comment: @Zeus Because this answer uses an array of characters (bytes) and you just copy different elements of the array to the right place.

Comment: `mvbits` is unnecessary because you're not bit-twiddling but byte-twiddling.  Sadly Fortran seems to lack a `mvbytes` routine.

Comment: That's because a single character is 1 byte?

Comment: @Zeus that is a definition of a byte, addressable unit able to hold a basic character.

Answer (score 0):

It is even possible to do this without `transfer`:

```
program test
  implicit none
  character(len=*),parameter  :: src = '1234'
  integer,parameter           :: perm(4) = [2,4,3,1]
  character(len=len(src))     :: dst
  integer                     :: i

  do i=1,len(src)
    dst(i:i) = src(perm(i):perm(i))
  enddo
  print *,src,'->',dst
end program
```

Comment: Yes indeed, but this approach won't work if the input and output are `real`s or `integer`s.

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark That is true, then you need the `transfer`.

Comment: I thought characters are not affected by endianness!

Comment: @Zeus: why are you now throwing endian-ness into the mix ?  In passing: all bytes are potentially affected by endian-ness.